# Kafka Streams: Add Sequence to each message within a group of message

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

**Set Up**

Kafka 2.5

Apache KStreams 2.4

Deployment to Openshift(Containerized)

**Objective**

1. Group a set of messages from a topic using a set of value attributes & assign a unique group identifier
   -- This can be achieved by using selectKey and groupByKey

```
originalStreamFromTopic
.selectKey((k,v)-> String.join("|",v.attribute1,v.attribute2))
.groupByKey()

groupedStream.mapValues((k,v)-> 
{ 
   v.setGroupKey(k);
   return v; 
});
```

2. For each message within a specific group , create a new message with an itemCount number as one of the attributes
   e.g. A group  with key "keypart1|keyPart2"  can have 10 messages and each of the message should have an incremental id from 1 through 10.

```
aggregate?
count and some additional StateStore based implementation.
```

One of the options (that i listed above), can make use of a couple of state stores
state store 1-> Mapping of each groupId and individual Item (KTable)
state store 2 -> Count per groupId (KTable)

A join of these 2 tables to stamp a sequence on the message as they get published to the final topic.

**Other statistics:**

Average number of messages per group would be in some 1000s except for an outlier case where it can go upto 500k.
In general the candidates for a group should be made available on the source within a span of 15 mins max.

**Following points are of concern from the optimum solution perspective .**

1. I am still not clear how i would be able to stamp a sequence number on the messages unless some kind of state store is used for keeping track of messages published within a group.
2. Use of KTable and state stores (either explicit usage or implicitly by the use of KTable) , would add to the state store size considerably.
   Given the problem involves some kind of tasteful processing , the state store cant be avoided but any possible optimizations might be useful.

Any thoughts or references to similar patterns would be helpful.

Comment: You basically want to change the key of each message to a composite key and stamp each message with an ID that increments after each message. Is my undersatnding correct? Must the ID be globally unique or just for a bunch of messages?

Comment: Thanks. Yes .the composite key is what is expected for a bunch of messages  e.g. if there are 100 messages on  topic, there can be 10 groups with groupIds & individual items within a group have sequence number from 1 to 10. concerns are 1..Group size not known upfront-> we can solve this by aggregation. AFAIK aggregate values are stored in a keystore backed by (kafka generated) a topic implicitly. So, size of the aggregated message has to be optimum 2. Storing individual items in a KTable during aggregation (key- groupId+mess.Seq).Issue is aggregator doesnt have access to state store .

Comment: Would it work if you just have one state store with which you maintain the ID for each composite key? When you get a message you select a new composite key and you lookup the next ID for the composite key in the state store. Then, you stamp the message with the new ID that you just looked up. Would that work or do I miss something?

Comment: Agree with usage of state store and specific look up(and it does make sense).I have implemented a version of the solution using a similar approach. 2 problems i have not got answers yet.1)  The atomicity of the count being used i.e. race condition causing 2 elements having same sequence number within a group. 2) Along with the composite key store , need to have a store for the individual items of the group. Finally the individual items will get pushed and a one container message at a group level. on NFR side, I plan to check state store performance with some artificial messages.

Comment: If the ID is stamped per composite key, you will not run into race conditions because messages with the same composite key are processed by the same stream thread and the corresponding state store that holds the ID of the composite key is maintained by the same stream thread as well, so there is no concurrency.
I cannot follow your second point. What do you mean with "one container message"? What does NFR mean? After stamping the messages, what happens with the messages? Do they need to be aggregated or just pushed to a topic?

Comment: NFR- Non functional  Container Message- A single message emitted for a group of messages having same composite Key. Post stamping they to onto a topic. On the point about the composite id being processed by Same Stream thread-> Within a stream thread there can be multiple tasks which will get the State Store shards assigned to them. If we try to stamp GroupId and sequence number on the individual item, (keep a running count of the messages in a group) is there a chance that 2 tasks access the state store for same ID simultaneously and thus the current count becomes incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one state store with which you maintain the ID for each composite key. When you get a message you select a new composite key and then you lookup the next ID for the composite key in the state store. You stamp the message with the new ID that you just looked up. Finally, you increase the ID and write it back to the state store.

Code-wise, it would be something like:

```
// create state store
StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String,String>> keyValueStoreBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
    Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("idMaintainer"),
    Serdes.String(),
    Serdes.Long()
);

// add store
builder.addStateStore(keyValueStoreBuilder);

originalStreamFromTopic
    .selectKey((k,v)-> String.join("|",v.attribute1,v.attribute2))
    .repartition()
    .transformValues(() -> new ValueTransformer() {
            private StateStore state;

            void init(ProcessorContext context) {
                state = context.getStateStore("idMaintainer");
            }

            NewValueType transform(V value) {
                // your logic to:
                // - get the ID for the new composite key, 
                // - stamp the record
                // - increase the ID
                // - write the ID back to the state store
                // - return the stamped record
            }
     
            void close() {
            }

        }, "idMaintainer")
    .to("output-topic");
```

You do not need to worry about concurrent access to the state store because in Kafka Streams same keys are processed by one single task and tasks do not share state stores. That means, your new composite keys with the same value will be processed by one single task that exclusively maintains the IDs for the composite keys in its state store.

Comment: OP should at least recognise this answer as  works and if not why it doesn't.